# How could I move the button to the right next to the textarea

Tags: html, css

The search box contains one input tag and one a tag. It looks like the image below. I want to move the button the right next the textarea like the second image.  I tried the "float", but it didn't work. Could someone help me to figure out ?

```html
    <div class="search">
      <input type="text" placeholder="Search here..." class="validate">
      <a class="waves-effect waves-light btn">Search</a>
    </div>
```

[actual output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TTyZs.png)

[desired output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hRQqh.png)

Comment: Include your full CSS or make a JSFiddle

Comment: I would guess that float didn't work because of specificity. Check the element in the devtools and see how CSS is applied and if your float is being overridden...

Comment: without any css of yours, no way to help you without just doing the whole job for you :)

Answer (score 1):

flex could still be an option:

```css
.search {
  display:flex;
  margin:50px 1em 1em;
  }
input {
  flex:1;
  }
a {
  padding:1em;
  background:tomato;
```

```html
<div class="search">
      <input type="text" placeholder="Search here..." class="validate">
      <a class="waves-effect waves-light btn">Search</a>
    </div>
                                                                                              <br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><a href="http://codepen.io/gcyrillus/pen/jqOdMg">demo</a>
```